# PostgreSQL - Alterar nome de várias colunas de uma vez

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela no PostgreSQL com colunas que estão com nomes "c0001", "c0992","c3993", e assim por diante. Começam com c e depois vem um número "aleatório".

Tenho um dicionário em .csv explicando cada uma delas e com um apelido. Ex:

```
    Conta  |        Descricao            | Apelido
    c0001  | Valor disponível em caixa   |  Caixa
    c0992  | Valor do Patrimônio Líquido |  PL
     ...   |            ....             |  ...
```

Para renomear  a coluna, usaria

```
ALTER TABLE schema.balanco RENAME c0001 TO Caixa
```

Preciso fazer isso para as 204 colunas. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso sem que precise digitar uma a uma?

Comment: vai no notepad++, gera um macro, monta o script completo...

Comment: Você pode abrir o arquivo com qualquer editor de texto que permita executar substituição de palavras com expressão regular e mandar substituir `\s+\|.*\|\s+` por ` TO ` e depois mandar substituir `    ` (espaços no início de cada linha) por `ALTER TABLE schema.balanco RENAME `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segui as dicas dos amigos e resolvi da seguinte maneira:

importei o arquivo no R e usei os comandos:

```r
library(stringr)

Plano_Contas$CONTA <- str_c("COMMENT ON COLUMN schema.balanco.c",Plano_Contas$CONTA)

Plano_Contas$NOME_CONTA <- str_c(" IS '",Plano_Contas$NOME_CONTA,"';")

write.csv(Plano_Contas,"planocontas.csv")
```

Abri o .csv em Excel, copiei as duas colunas e colei no PostgreSQL

Deu certo.